# how to remove repetition of data in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is my detail table:

[image]

This is my contact table:

[image]

Here are two rows in **details** table and 4 rows (each details have 2) in **contact** table. When I use join query I get 4 results row but I want only 2 row(one row of details row with one contact of that corresponding details).

my query:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('dots_center_detail');
$this->db->join('dots_center_contact', 'dots_center_contact.registration_id = dots_center_detail.registration_id','left');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$this->db->query("
  SELECT DISTINCT dots_center_detail.registration_id,  dots_center_contact.contact
  FROM dots_center_detail
  LEFT JOIN dots_center_contact ON dots_center_contact.registration_id = dots_center_detail.registration_id
")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `select('DISTINCT *')` in place of `select('*')` may give the result you need. It's worth a try.

Or you can create a view like this to go with your table definitions.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW dots_center_unique_contact AS
    SELECT DISTINCT * FROM dots_center_contact;
```

Then refer to that `dots_center_unique_contact` view in your join operation.

Your best bet long term is to figure out why you have duplicate rows, and tighten up your business rules so you don't.